Negating the verb and negating the subject 's property
What is the strict and exact relation (implication, equivalence etc.) between these two sentences?:
I. Alcibiades is not wise. (Negating the subject 's property)
II. Alcibiades is not (=isn 't) wise. (Negating the copula)
At a first glance we have something similar to set theoretic equivalence "x belongs to set not-S (S' complement), iff x doesn 't belong to set S". Though in sentences
I'. Alcibiades is in not-Sparta,
II'. Alcibiades isn' t in Sparta
it seems we have something different: at (I') Alcibiades is surely somewhere but somewhere else than Sparta and at (II') maybe Alcibiades is nowhere but for sure he isn 't in Sparta.
My question is about generalizing such forms -and even wider predicates, i.e. not necessarily sentences with copula but also sentences with subject, verb and object (e.g. I''. Paganini plays not cello and II''. Paganini doesn 't play cello)- and find if there is some dependence from verb 's or other terms' semantics.  Every bibliographic reference is welcome.

Provided that the negation of the predicate is the "complement", the two are the same. I mean: white is not the same as not-black.

@MauroALLEGRANZA 1) My post is not about gradable opposites such "black/white". It is only about cotradictory opposites of the form "X/not-X".  2) Provided (1) you confirm right my thought, but 3) what about the rest of my post and my general question? Thanks!

In many languages, negating the subject, usually with  privative prefixes or suffixes as in "Alcibiades is unwise", has the effect of replacing the contradictory (logical negation) with a contrary. Aristotle says, for example, "we do not call that toothless which has not teeth, or that blind which has not sight, but rather that which has not teeth or sight at the time when by nature it should." Privative negation is discussed in SEP, but I am not sure if this is what you are after.

It depends on the logical form of the statement. Not (Socrates is Greek) is the same as (Socrates is not-Greek), but not-(every man is mortal) is not the same as (every man is not mortal).

@Conifold you are talking in an apt manner about στερητικὸν (~privative). The aristotelean passage hides something interesting: It is primary for negating to make sense, e.g. the sentence "this mountain is unclever" is meanless. Formally the subject must join the frame that the attached attribute imposes via predication (of course "mountain" does not join "cleverness" in any literal way). Therefore you contribute on the frame 's potential necessity. But what about then?

I’m going to use a different example to elucidate what I think is the main difference between negating the verb and negating the subject.

The sky is not red.
The sky is not red.

The first is just saying the sky doesn’t have the property ‘red’, while the second is actually affirming that the sky has the property ‘not red’. If “A is not B” is the extensional negation of “A is B” and if ‘not-red’ is the complement of ‘red’, then they’re just saying the same thing.
That is not to say that there are not different ways to understand these concepts, especially since incorporating human notions of collections into formal set theory isn’t usually feasible. The collection of everything that isn’t a turtle contains itself, so in most set theories, no such collection can be modeled. I really don’t know much about NBG and MK, but I think you might have a chance at formalizing it in one of those theories by calling such a collection the class of everything that is not a turtle. In those theories, proper classes cannot be members of classes, so Russell’s Paradox doesn’t apply. You can see more about these class theories here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/von+Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del+set+theory
That is all to say that not every property we can cook up in natural language corresponds to a set, but since there are class theories with the Class Existence Theorem, we can be sure that in those theories we have a class of all and only those classes that have property A, where A is definable in terms of the language of class theory. As it stands, class theories have complements because they have a universal class. So, the examples mentioned would, depending on the way you formalize them, still yield the same result of being equivalent.

What’s with the downvote?


What is the strict and exact relation (implication, equivalence etc.) between these two sentences?:
I. Alcibiades is not wise. (Negating the subject 's property)
II. Alcibiades is not (=isn 't) wise. (Negating the copula)

my best guess at a constructive reading would be that I. is a assertion of negation, as in
⊢ ¬W(a)
while II. is about lack/absence of proof/evidence for W(a), maybe even, though not necessarily,
⊬ W(a)

I'. Alcibiades is in not-Sparta,

to affirm such it seems to be necessary to pick some especific place P(-) such that
⊢ ∀x( [ P(x) → ¬S(x) ] ∧ [ S(x) → ¬P(x) ] )
and moreover
⊢ P(a)
[which i suppose matches your interpretation,] and in particular this implies

II'. Alcibiades isn' t in Sparta

⊢ ¬S(a)
[again matching your interpretation,] but this by itself may not provide especific P(-)

Many to comment here! I start from this: It seems weird for Proposition (II) to be thought as a "proof incomplete" one, for, if (II) is supposed to be true, then we are provided a complete assurance (at least from a logical point of view) of its valency. I could state the main problem of the first pair (I,II) as such: Inside a (logical) predicate how takes place the "negation 's transition" from verb to it 's object or to subject 's grammatical predicate (κατηγορούμενον)?

Being natural language phrases, there is no one way to capture their semantics using just syntax.  Don't be surprised when there's multiple answers.
That being said, a common case where the pattern of "Subject negated-verb Object" is different from "Subject verb negated-object" is in a language of assertions, which is inherently modal.  In a modal language, there is some concept of something between true and false.  The most obvious of them is one which is "unknown" -- potentially either true or false, but not yet known.
In that sense, "Alcibiades is not-wise" may explicitly declare that Wise(Alcibades) is false, while "Alchebades isn't wise" may declare that Wise(Alcibades) isn't true, but may be unknown.

I suppose there is a slight confusion here. Let's take the first comparative example:
"Alcibiades is not wise"
"Alcibiades is not wise" (is not) = (isnt)
We predicate the negation of the property in the first sentence, and we do not predicate the property in the second sentence. (So we deny the copula through which the predicate "is wise" holds). Those are rightfully equivalent. Now let's take the second comparative example
"Alcibiades is not in Sparta"
"Alcibiades is in not-Sparta"
The paradoxical element comes from the fact that you didnt follow the form of the first comparative example. The first sentence posits the denial of predicate "in Sparta", but the second sentence doesnt actually follow the form of the first sentence of the first comparative example, since you are still preserving the term "in", which composes the predicate. That is, "Alcibiades is in not-Sparta" is not really positing the denial of the predicate, rather the correct correlate is exactly the same: "alcibiades is not in Sparta", in which "not in Sparta" is the negative predicate which is posited by the copula "is". Ultimately you forgot to make the "not" antecede the predicate since you included the "in". The same problem arises in the Paganini example. "Paganini plays not Cello" is not really a sentence which posits the denial of the predicate "plays Cello". One way to see this is converting it to "Paganini does play not Cello". You still included part of the predicate. In reality, the proper correlate is "Paganini does not play Cello", in which "not play Cello" is the negative predicate posited by "does".
The notion of x being in not-S if x is not in S is simply to affirm the negation of "x is in S". Basically, if we deny that x is in S, we affirm that we deny that x is in S, and thus we posit that x is in not-S. We are playing with the fact that anything stands so long as it is posited/affirmed. That's also why most people think that untruth entails falsity, (That is, if p is not true then ~p is true) since falsity is reduced to the truth of untruth, the truth of negation.

I agree about the "Sparta" example. Though "Alcibiades" and "Paganini" examples are still similar. About the "Alcibiades" example, please, see my answer. There you can find a reasoning as such: The sentence "π is not rational" has meaning and it is false, because π and rationals are real numbers (presence of common frame); the sentence "the complex number 1+i is not a rational number" has no meaning, because rationals belong to real numbers, but complex numbers do not (lack of common frame). Therefore simple predication incorporates something more than we see.

The sentence "π is not rational" not only has meaning but it is also true, since there do not exist numbers p and q such that p/q = π and p and q are integers. The same reasoning follow for complex numbers, so i dont understand your point. To posit that π is not a rational number isnt to say that there is no set to which they both pertain, but only that π doesnt pertain to the set of rational numbers. And complex numbers and real numbers are both in the set of all numbers.

I made a mistake as I was writing my comment (but I do not know how to fix it!). Of course "π is not rational" is true.

About "the set of all numbers": Before we deside about the truth value of "x belongs to S" we have to include x in some set, which is also superset of S; I have never found in math books something like "the set of all numbers".

I will try to give an interpretation.
I consider that affirmation of a negative property inserts the subject into a frame submitted by the property. On the other hand negation of a property does not oblige subject to penetrate any frame. Specifically the affirmation
X is not-P
inserts X into a genus-frame containing P (e.g. "My garden 's rose is not-red" implies that my garden 's rose has a colour, which is other than red). The negation
X is-not P
just says that X has not the property P without any innuendo about X belonging to some frame (e.g. "Euclidean geometry is-not red" is acceptable, because the subject has no colour at all).
If by coincidence X belongs to the frame submitted by property, then the two forms have identical meanings.

The complement of a set can only be defined if a universal set is defined.  There is no complement of a set in ZF set theory.  Your confusion can be resolved using the logic of naive set theory instead of ZFC set theory.
Alcibiades is non-wise = Alcibiades is an element of the set of things that aren't wise.
Alcibiades isn't wise = not (Alcibiades is wise) = Alcibiades doesn't have the property 'wise'.
Symbolize Alcibiades is wise by W(a).
Thus Alcibiades isn't wise = ~W(a).
Let W denote the set of all things that are wise and only things that are wise.
W = {x| W(x) }
Let W' denote the complement of W.
W' = {x| ~W(x) }
Alcibiades is non-wise means, in naive set theory that, ~W(a).
If Alcibiades isn't wise, then he's an element of W', and conversely.
Thus the two statements are equivalent if you use naive set theory.
Alcibiades isn't in Sparta = not (Alcibiades is in Sparta).
Here, Sparta isn't a set, it's a place.  Thus, is-in isn't the elementhood relation of set theory.
Alcibiades is in non-Sparta has the same confusion.  Sparta isn't a set.
